# Printfn value is not a function and cannot be applied in F#'s interactive window

Tags: f#, fsi, unit-type

This is probably something simple, but I have a .fs file with a simple sample function.

```
let printHello = printfn "%A" "Hello"
```

I have set the search path to the .fs file using

```
>#I "PathToMyFSFile"
```

I have loaded my file using

```
>#load "Test.fs"
```

Which worked fine. Now I want to call the function which actually prints the hello to screen, but thats turning out to be too difficult

```
> Test.printHello;;
val it : unit = ()
```

Tried Test.printHello();; as well but doesn't work. How do I actually make it print "Hello" to screen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your current `printHello` isn't actually a function.  To make it a function you need to do

```
let printHello() = printfn "%A" "Hello"
```

noice the `()`.  Then everything should work.

EDIT:

When the compiler sees your definition

```
let printHello = printfn "%A" "Hello"
```

it passes it as a simple data term.  For example, consider this program:

```
let printHello = printfn "%A" "Hello"
printfn "World"
printHello
```

This will print `"Hello"` then `"World"`.  `printHello` just has unit type, so does nothing.  Compare it to

```
let printHello() = printfn "%A" "Hello"
printfn "World"
printHello()
```

Here `printHello` is a function.  In this case, the function is only executed when it is explicitly called, so this prints `"World"` then `"Hello"`.

Comment: So what did I end up declaring printHello as anyway then? isn't it a partial/curried function that I can pass around or execute later when I am ready? How do I do that?

Comment: The interactive window is telling you exactly what it is - a value of the unit type `()`.  My version is what you can pass around as a function.  I will add some more explaination in the answer

Answer (score 5):

As John already said, your `printHello` isn't a function - it is a value of type `unit`. When you give `printfn` all the required arguments (as you did), it does the imperative operation and return `unit` (which is a type with only a single value written as `()`). You can see that writing that declaration does the printing immediately:

```
> let printHello = printfn "%A" "Hello";;
"Hello"
val printHello : unit = ()
```

When you use `printHello` later, it simply refers to this `unit` value (which does not carry any information).

If you want to make it a function (of type `unit -> unit`) that will do something each time it is executed, then you can use the sample that John posted.

The function `printfn` was not *partially applied*, because you gave it all the parameters it required (so it could just print immediately). If you wanted to use partial application, you could use something like:

```
> let printHello = printfn "%s %s" "Hello";; // Note - didn't give value for second %s
val printHello : string -> unit
```

Now `printHello` is a function that waits for the second parameter and then runs:

```
> printHello "World";;
Hello World
val it : unit = ()

> printHello "F#";;
Hello F#
val it : unit = ()
```

Comment: Your explanation around currying made the penny drop. Didn't realise that by passing all the parameters, I was executing it immediately and hence ending up with the 'result' of the function rather than the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been said in other answers, "printHello" set to () is unit, the return value of printfn is () , console print is side-effect.

use Lazy:

```
let printHello = Lazy (fun () ->printfn "%A" "Hello")
```

**DEMO**

```
> Test.printHello.Value;;
"Hello"
val it : unit = ()
> Test.printHello.Value;;
val it : unit = () //only once
```

use Seq:

```
let printHello = seq { printfn "%A" "Hello"; yield ()}
```

**DEMO**

```
> Test.printHello;;
"Hello"
val it : seq<unit> = seq [null]
> Test.printHello;;
"Hello"
val it : seq<unit> = seq [null] //many times
```

Comment: Your syntax for creating lazy values seems wrong. It should be either `Lazy.Create (fun () -> printfn "Hello")` (using a function) or it should be `lazy printfn "Hello"` using language feature.